Swift 5 Memory loss from transitions
My app appears to be slowly leaking memory just from transitioning between VCs, even with the most basic setup.  I want to fade between VC hence the setup using CATransition.
If I switch between the IntroVC and the FirstVC repeatedly, gradually over time the memory usage creeps up.  It's a very slow increase (perhaps 0.1 MB for every twenty back-and-forths?) but it is increasing, so something is not being released somewhere.  And as soon as I add other elements, background, images etc., the memory jumps up about 0.2 for every time I load a repeated VC.
This could be because of an inherent fault with 'popping' and 'pushing' but that seems unlikely, or it could be because of the way I've structured things.
I've attempted to use the Instruments in order to be able to isolate the leak, but am not really sure what it's telling me.
Anybody with any ideas?
My AppDelegate:
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var coordinator: MainCoordinator?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        setupCore()
        return true
    }
    
    //MARK: - Setup methods
    private func setupCore() {
        let navController = UINavigationController()
        coordinator = MainCoordinator(navigationController: navController)
        coordinator?.start()
    
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = navController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}

My MainCoordinator:
import UIKit

class MainCoordinator: NSObject, Coordinator, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var childCoordinators = [Coordinator]()
    var navigationController: UINavigationController
    var rootIntro: IntroVC!
    
    init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.navigationController = navigationController
        self.navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }
    
    func start() {
        navigationController.delegate = self
        rootIntro = IntroVC.instantiate()
        rootIntro.coordinator = self
        navigationController.fadeTo(rootIntro)
    }
    
    //MARK: - Loading VCs from Intro
    func showFirst() {
        let vc = FirstVC.instantiate()
        vc.coordinator = self
        navigationController.fadeTo(vc)
    }

    
    // MARK: - Leaving VCs
    func returnToRoot() {
        navigationController.fadeToRoot()
    }
}

The Coordinator protocol:
protocol Coordinator: AnyObject {
    var childCoordinators: [Coordinator] { get set }
    var navigationController: UINavigationController { get set }
    
    func start()
}

// MARK: - Storyboard
protocol Storyboarded {
    static func instantiate() -> Self
}

extension Storyboarded where Self: UIViewController {
    static func instantiate() -> Self  {
        let id = String(describing: self)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: id) as! Self
    }
}

The extension for UINavigationController:
extension UINavigationController {
    func fadeTo(_ toVC: UIViewController) {
        let transition = CATransition().fadeTransition()
        view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
        pushViewController(toVC, animated: false)
    }

    func fadeToRoot() {
        let transition = CATransition().fadeTransition()
        view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
        popToRootViewController(animated: false)
    }
}
extension CATransition {
    func fadeTransition() -> CATransition {
        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.3
        transition.type = CATransitionType.fade
        return transition
    }
}

The IntroVC:
class IntroVC: UIViewController, Storyboarded {

    weak var coordinator: MainCoordinator?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let title = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100),
                                          size: CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 80)))
        title.text = "Intro VC"
        title.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .heavy)
        title.textAlignment = .center
        title.textColor = .lightGray
        view.addSubview(title)
        
        
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: (view.frame.width - 150)/2, y: (view.frame.height - 50)/2),
                                            size: CGSize(width: 150, height: 50)))
        button.backgroundColor = .green
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("-> First", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
    
    @objc func tapped(_ button: UIButton) {
        coordinator?.showFirst()
    }
}

And finally the FirstVC:

class FirstVC: UIViewController, Storyboarded  {

    weak var coordinator: MainCoordinator?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let title = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100),
                                          size: CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 80)))
        title.text = "First VC"
        title.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .heavy)
        title.textAlignment = .center
        title.textColor = .white
        view.addSubview(title)
        
        
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: (view.frame.width - 150)/2, y: (view.frame.height - 50)/2),
                                            size: CGSize(width: 150, height: 50)))
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("<- Intro", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
    
    @objc func tapped(_ button: UIButton) {
        coordinator?.returnToRoot()
    }
}


You posted too many irrelevant code to see what's happening. You said so something is not being released somewhere. You can Debug Memory Graph with Xcode to identify that object easily.

“Memory leak” in Swift means “you have a strong reference to an object that you shouldn’t have”.
Most likely cause is a circular reference. A refers to B and B refers to A, and X refers to A. If you remove the reference X->A, neither A nor B can be accessed anymore, but both have a strong reference to each other which keeps them alive.
My bets are on the button: addTarget(self, ..,) which stores a reference to the UIViewController.

I just checked the docs on addTarget(_:action:for:). They say: "The control does not retain the object in the target parameter. It is your responsibility to maintain a strong reference to the target object while it is attached to a control." So that rules that out as the culprit.
